# Start a script from react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to react and web programming and I am getting a little bit confused. I created a reactjs website which contain a `Start` button. When the user clicks on the button, I want to run a `nodejs` script hosted on the server which host the website itself and report the progress to the user. Is it possible to execute the script directly from react or shall I create an API,for example REST, and use it to accept the start requests? I know that HTML is displayed on the user side and therefore it could not execute a script on the server but I am not sure how the things with react works as I have to start the server which is rendering the code...

Comment: React is client side when on the browser, it doesn’t change anything in the way you communicate between server and client. So you’ll need some endpoint to talk to on the server.

Comment: you would need to create an endpoint which react could post to and then you respond on the post on your backend to start your node.js process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is a client side library and it has got nothing to do with server side execution other than triggering it. Easiest you could do is create a rest API using [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) or any of the web framework and write the code to be executed in the handler of the API endpoint.

Something similar to this would do

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/execute-script', (req, res) => {
    //write your logic for execution
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```